# C#のDataGridViewのオートフィルター値を再検索後も保持したいです

Tags: c#, winforms

以下のようにDataGridViewのHeaderCellに
DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCellを設定して
エクセルのオートフィルターの簡易版を実装しています。

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in DataGridView.Columns)  {
     col.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(col.HeaderCell);
 }
```

現状フィルタ動作はこれで問題ないのですが、
再検索時にフィルターを設定していた場合にフィルターの内容を保持したいです。
（現状ではフィルターの選択は検索毎に解除されます。）

このためには検索前に一度フィルターで何を選択していたか保持して、
検索後、DataGridViewの内容が更新された後に保持しておいたフィルター値で
フィルタリングする必要があると考えています。

DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCellの外からフィルター選択値の取得、
フィルター値の設定とフィルタ動作をすることは可能でしょうか？
それともヘッダー部分をカスタム部品化するしかないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

`DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell`の実装を確認すると、リセット時の動作は

```
private void ResetFilter()
{
    if (this.DataGridView == null) return;
    BindingSource source = this.DataGridView.DataSource as BindingSource;
    if (source == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(source.Filter))
    {
        filtered = false;
        selectedFilterValue = "(All)";
        currentColumnFilter = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

となっており、`BindingSource`の`Filter`を指定しておけばリセットされないように見えます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
お伝えできておりませんでしたが、今回テーブルのカラムを毎回動的に作成しなおすため、DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCellも毎回newしており、リセットも毎回されてしまいます。ただ、上記の「BindingSourceのFilterを指定しておけば」が大変参考になり、filtered ,selectedFilterValue ,currentColumnFilter のpublicのsetter,getterを設け、selectedFilterValue,currentColumnFilter を検索前に保持しておき、検索後newしたDataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCellにfiltered ,selectedFilterValue ,currentColumnFilter を設定しなおすことで実現できました！ありがとうございました。